# SQLCLR using the wrong version of the .NET Framework

Tags: .net, sql-server, sqlclr, sql-server-2008-r2

During a recent restart of our development server the `SQL Server` started using `.NET 4.0` for the SQLCLR. This means that nothing using the CLR in SQL works, or at least that's my understanding by reading these sources:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2009/10/16/sql-server-2008-sqlclr-net-framework-version/

[www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/BOBB/post/On-SQL-Server-and-NET-40.aspx](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/BOBB/post/On-SQL-Server-and-NET-40.aspx)

All we get are error messages of this type:

> Msg 6517, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Failed to create AppDomain
>   "xxx.dbo[ddl].3".  Method's type signature is not Interop compatible.

Running the statement (as suggested by @john-christensen)

```
select * from sys.dm_clr_properties
```

results in the following information:

```
*Name*      *Value*
directory   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\
version     v4.0.30319
state       CLR is initialized
```

Does anyone know how to solve this or how we can force SQL Server CLR to use an earlier version of the Framework?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Typically you can force a .NET application to use a specific .NET Framework version by specifying the `supportedRuntime` tag in the application's config file.

So you could try creating a `sqlservr.exe.config` in the `\Binn` folder under the root path of the SQL instance and specify there that you would like to use only .NET versions up to 3.5. Check [this MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx34a2h.aspx) for the structure of the config file.

Answer (score 15):

I experienced the same annoying problem. None of the Geography/Geometry stuff in my database worked. Took me some unsuccessful reinstalls of SQL server to finally (some weeks later!) find the following key in my registry had been set to '1'

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\\.NETFramework\OnlyUseLatestCLR
```

when I reset it to '0', and rebooted the machine, things worked again!

Answer (score 9):

From the article and my research on the web, it looks like the opposite might be happening - could you potentially be registering a 4.0 DLL? It appears that SQL Server 2008 will always load the 2.0 CLR and not the 4.0 CLR. Try running this statement, it will tell you what version your SQL server is running:

```
select * from sys.dm_clr_properties
```

Comment: When I run the select * from sys.dm_clr_properties I get the following:  
"directory:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\  
version:v4.0.30319  
state:CLR is initialized"
  
which to me indicates that it is v4.0 that's used.

Comment: I've added the response to that statement to the main question aswell.

Answer (score 7):

In your post at Intel that you reference, if you read it closely, it says:

> SQL Server 2008 and the forthcoming
>   SQL Server 2008 R2 release, previously
>   codenamed "Kilimanjaro", **will both
>   continue to load the latest service
>   release of the version 2.0 CLR**.

And later on:

> While future versions of SQL Server
>   may load newer versions of the CLR, or
>   even support the loading of multiple
>   CLR's within the process, **version 2.0
>   of the CLR is here to stay for SQLCLR
>   within SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server
>   2008 R2.**

I don't know how you manage to get something like .NET 4 loaded inside SQL Server 2008 R2....

Answer (score 1):

They made explicit choices to ensure that installation of .NET 4.0 would be non-impactful.  It shouldn't be using .NET 4.0 or any of the new files except for the new shim files, mscoree.dll and mscoreei.dll.  Those should be backward compatible with the 2.0 runtime.  You could run Process Explorer to see the version numbers of the dll's loaded to verify that it is running the right runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem for a day and after updating my windows and .NET frameworks problem disappeared.the problem relates to .Net framework try to repair it.