# CLR stored procedure needs to call .Net Assembly

Tags: .net

I have a CLR stored procedure which is written .Net 3.5 due to the limitations of SQL Server 2008

From within this stored procedure I need to call a function which is in a .Net 4.0 assembly but when I add a reference to it I get the error

> ' ', or one of its dependencies requires a later version of the .Net
>   Framework than the one specified in the project...

Is there any way around this?

The assembly I am calling is an external assembly so I am not able to make any changes to it, but I do need to call it from my CLR?   Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [MSDN Forum Post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxgeneralprerelease/thread/bef443cc-5413-4322-8d9a-117abd2386d3) the CLR's are not forward compatable.  It is talking about 
2.0 to 4.0 communication, it is still appropriate for 3.5 to 4.0 also.

> There is also not any direct CLR-to-CLR communication provided by CLR. Usage of COM is probably the best idea.
>   Also note that 2.0 assembly can communicate with 4.0 assembly, but they have to run in the same CLR runtime (4.0 in this case). Assemblies by themselves are not restricted as 2.0 assembly can run in 4.0 CLR runtime. The CLR runtime version is the important part, not the CLR which the assembly was build against.

Comment: I am not sure i understand what this comment means??

Comment: Does this mean it is not possible?

Comment: It looks like the only way would be if your third party assembly was built with a COM interface. So other than that no. You can add an assembly built on an earlier runtime to a 4.0 project but you can not add an assembly built on 4.0 to a 3.5 or earlier project.

Comment: Do you have any good information on COM interfaces? while it is a third-party assembly we want to call from our CLR, we do have the full source for it so we can extend it

Comment: COM can be quite a deep subject, I have always just consumed COM objects in my code. I have not had the need to create. There are some good books on Amazon and some decent documentation on MSDN plus there are some qood questions and answers on Stackoverflow. i.e.  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=making+.net+assembly+com+visible

Comment: Yeah they are a little over my head at the moment, so there is no other way to call the methods in the .Net 4 assemblies that you can think of?

Comment: No I can not think of any. They purposely did not put the ability to intercommunicate between clr's.

Comment: It looks like SQL Server 2008 sp1 was .Net 3.5 and according to this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675218.aspx SQL Server 2008 R2 is 3.5 or greater

Comment: That is ADO.Net though not Sql Server itself, i believe you can still only set the CLR version in SQL Server R2 to 3.5 (which is effectively v2.0.50727), http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2009/10/16/sql-server-2008-sqlclr-net-framework-version/

Comment: You are right according to this link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2009/12/09/sql-server-express-and-net-4.aspx. It probably won't be supported to Denalai is released.