# Cannot install assembly on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, clr, sqlclr, sqlanywhere

I made some library and want to use it as CLR assembly in MSSQL. The point is that my lib have the reference to 'iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere' lib which I cannot install. The error is:

> Assembly
>   'iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere' could not be installed because existing
>   policy would keep it from being used.

I have implemented the recommendations and now my SQL looks like:

```
USE DB_Control
GO 

ALTER DATABASE DB_Control SET TRUSTWORTHY ON WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO

ALTER DATABASE DB_Control SET TRUSTWORTHY ON
GO

exec sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO

RECONFIGURE;
GO

exec sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1;
GO

RECONFIGURE;
GO

CREATE ASSEMBLY [iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere]
AUTHORIZATION sa
FROM '~\Debug\iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
GO

CREATE ASSEMBLY ClrSqlMediator
AUTHORIZATION sa
FROM '~\Debug\SQLMediator.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
GO
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

---

**Upd:** Server version is SQL Server 2008 R2 (x64).
My MediatorCLR built as x64 lib, but I almost shure SQLAnywhere.dll built as x86. Can it be the reason?

---

**Upd2:** Here is Dropbox link to libs:
x64 - [https](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/34563568/x64.rar),
x86 - [https](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/34563568/x86.rar).

---

**Upd3:** I start thinking that SQLAnywhere.dll cannot be loaded at all because of x86 build option and I'm not sure that it has public static methods that is required. Surely i got to implement some other kind of reference.

Comment: Wrong .NET version? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781624/sqlclr-using-the-wrong-version-of-the-net-framework

Comment: Which is the version of SQL Server?

Comment: Check if there are 3rd party assemblies that are referred by SQLAnywhere.dll.

Comment: Check with Fuslogvw if those assemblies are not correctly binded: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx

Comment: @SQLhint.com lib doesn't generate any log for fuslogvw

Comment: I would say to try with a simplified version of your assembly: comment all code, just let a simple hello world method and check this way.

Comment: my assembly works fine, i just cant install the lib it depends off

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to there clauses

```
FROM '~\Debug\iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.dll'
FROM '~\Debug\SQLMediator.dll'
```

Here you should specify a valid path from SQL Server machine, after you have copied that .dll on SQL Server machine.

**Alternatively**, in case you don't have access to SQL Server file system in order to copy your assembly file, you can [generate hex code](http://sqlhint.com/sqlserver/how-to/clr-generate-assembly-hex), then register .NET assembly:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY <AssemblyName.dll>
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
FROM <0x4D5A9000030000000400000.... generated hex code here>
WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE
GO
```

Comment: path is valid, i've shortened it before pasting here - it's too long