# Cannot create new DB in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

After right clicking on DB and trying to create a new DB this is the error I am getting

[image]

What am I missing? I tried re-installing SQL Server 2008 R2 already. Any other ideas?

Comment: Any previous version already installed (SQL Server 2005)? Was there any issues/warning during installation process? Which .NET framework you are using?

Comment: @KenanZahirovic : Nope. No previous versions installed. .NET framework is 4.0.30319

Comment: Can you try to create database using T-SQL? Open new query and execute "CREATE DATABASE test"

Comment: @KenanZahirovic : It is kinda stuck after executing the above mentioned query. It is showing debugging...
but doesn't seem like any progress even after 10 mins.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have an issues with .NET framework version. AFAIK, SQL Server 2008 needs .NET 2 and I'm not sure how is it working on your machine with .NET 4.0.3.

You can try to execute following query:

> select * from sys.dm_clr_properties

and see which version you are using in SQL Server. For more details read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781624/sqlclr-using-the-wrong-version-of-the-net-framework)